# opencv inRange pixel position

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to get some pixels that are in range of RGB color values

I use inRange function:

```
 mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
```

Now I get this mask and I need to do some operations with this filtered pixels - i.e. find distance between two random pixels

How I can make this?

If I call `print(image)` I get following array:

```
[[[ 78  94 107]
[ 82  97 113]
[ 87 102 118]
...
[101 114 116]
[108 120 122]
[109 121 123]]
```

As I understand this is array where keys are x and y pixel position and value is RGB code. But If I call `print(mask.nonzero())` I see

```
(array([126, 126, 126, ..., 168, 168, 168], dtype=int64),...)
```

And I don't really undestand what is in this array and in docs I didn't find type of returned value

Comment: What are `lower` and `upper` here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's RGB range -  ([25, 146, 190], [62, 220, 250])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `mask` is a 2d array, the [**`numpy.nonzero(..)`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) method will return a 2-tuple, the first item is an array of indices of the first coordinate that is non-zero, and the second tuple is an array of indices of the second coordinate that is non-zero.

You can [**`np.transpose(..)`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) this to obtain an *n×2* matrix with for each row the two coordinates of the pixel that is not zero, so:

```
print(np.transpose(mask.nonzero()))
```